# Construct a Distinguished Name with Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

In my ansible playbook I have a variable defining the OU DN I'd like to create.

```
my_ou: "OU=win10,OU=workstations,OU=mycompany"
domain_root: "DC=example,DC=com"
```

I'd like to convert `my_ou` to a list and create each OU.  The problem is that the loop does not know the path for each OU because it is an aggregation of the previous elements in the loop.

If I split `my_ou` on ',' and reverse the loop, I can print each OU in order of creation.  I can set the name by using `regex_replace`. However, I don't know how to construct the path.

For example:

```
- name: create required OU's
  win_domain_ou: 
    name: "{{ my_ou | regex_replace('^OU=') }}"
    path: ???? should be all items to the right of the current {{ item }},{{ domain_root }}
    state: present
  loop: "{{ my_ou.split(',') | reverse | list }}"
```

So, to be clear, the path for `OU=win10` should be `OU=workstations,OU=mycompany,DC=example,DC=com`

The `OU=workstations` path should be `OU=mycompany,DC=example,DC=com`

And so forth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the list of elements

```yaml
elements: "{{ my_ou.split(',') + domain_root.split(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
elements:
  - OU=win10
  - OU=workstations
  - OU=mycompany
  - DC=example
  - DC=com
```

and use [extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item }} path: {{ elements[idx|int:]|join(',') }}"
      loop: "{{ my_ou.split(',')|reverse }}"
      loop_control:
          extended: true
      vars:
        idx: "{{ my_ou.split(',')|length - ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
msg: 'item: OU=mycompany path: DC=example,DC=com'
msg: 'item: OU=workstations path: OU=mycompany,DC=example,DC=com'
msg: 'item: OU=win10 path: OU=workstations,OU=mycompany,DC=example,DC=com'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_ou: "OU=win10,OU=workstations,OU=mycompany"
    domain_root: "DC=example,DC=com"
    elements: "{{ my_ou.split(',') + domain_root.split(',') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item }} path: {{ elements[idx|int:]|join(',') }}"
      loop: "{{ my_ou.split(',')|reverse }}"
      loop_control:
          extended: true
      vars:
        idx: "{{ my_ou.split(',')|length - ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```